# Getting value from combobox to database

Tags: java, database, swing, user-interface

What particular command or algorithm should I use to get the value that is selected in the JComboBox then insert it into a particular database?

Comment: What have you tried? In which part are you stuck? For better help sooner please add a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) demonstrating your problem. As is your question is too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to get the value from the combobox and how to insert the value into a DB are two completely different questions.

As for extracting the value, you can using something in the lines of `String x = String.valueOf(JComboBox.getSelectedItem());` but as for how to push it into a DB - well, that's a much bigger question which depends on many variables, like your DB type, host, network, etc.

Answer (score 2):

To get the value selected,
String value=JComboBox.getSelectedItem().toString();

Answer (score 0):

Just as a heads up, you need to ensure you have initialized it and it has atleast an element else you'll get an exception. I'll use sqlite in this case but like they said earlier, Database logic is all up to you.

```
 public Stack() {
    JComboBox<Object> box = new JComboBox<Object>();
    // This can work
    Object value = box.getSelectedItem();
    DatabaseManager manager = new DatabaseManager();
    manager.init();
    if (DatabaseManager.insertRecord(value.toString()))
        System.out.println("Record Inserted");
    else
        System.out.println("Record Insertion Failed");
    }

   static class DatabaseManager {

    static Connection con;
    static Statement stmt;

    void init() {
        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            con = DriverManager
                    .getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:database.sqlite");
            if (!con.isClosed()) {
                stmt = con.createStatement();
                stmt.executeUpdate("create table if not exists item (id integer primary autoincrement, value varchar(100) not null");
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static boolean insertRecord(String item) {
        try {
            if (stmt.executeUpdate("insert into item (value) values('"
                    + item + "')") > 0)
                return true;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return false;
      }
    }
```

Comment: You can add the close statement for the Db connection